# Contacts framework raises exception on reading of imageData

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, cncontact

I try to fetch imageData after refetching `CNContact` using `unifiedContactWithIdentifier:keysToFetch:error:` and `CNContactImageDataKey` in Objective-C.

I'm using Xcode 7.0 building on iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9.0.2.

In runtime I always have the same exception `CNPropertyNotFetchedException` even refetching contact and checking `imageData` calling `imageDataAvailable‌`.

Here is the code:

```
if([currentNativeContact isKeyAvailable:CNContactImageDataKey] &&
    currentNativeContact.imageDataAvailable) {
    previewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:currentNativeContact.thumbnailImageData];
}  else {
    NSError *error;
    currentNativeContact = [self.contactsStore unifiedContactWithIdentifier:currentNativeContact.identifier keysToFetch:@[CNContactImageDataKey] error:&error];
    if(!error && currentNativeContact.imageDataAvailable)
        previewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:currentNativeContact.thumbnailImageData];                            
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `CNContactImageDataAvailableKey`, `CNContactImageDataKey` and `CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey` keys to the `keysToFetch`.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric answer is partially right. We need to add CNContactImageDataKey in keysToFetch. Otherwise, app will get a crash on imageData.